# Creating package that uses RcppArmadillo

Tags: r, inline, rcpp, armadillo

I have written functions using RcppArmadillo and inline packages, I am using windows 7, R-2.14.1 and Rtools215 are installed and the path is checked.

```
funs = cxxfunction(list(MHcpp = signature(…), IWcpp = signature(…),  c(code1,code2), 
plugin="RcppArmadillo" ) # No compline and I they work fine as expected.

Package.skeleton(“new”,funs) # to create the package skeleton and the dynamic libray
# to build the package  I use
R CMD INSTALL –build new # I get the following error
C:/Users/samuel/Documents/R/win-library/2.14/Rcpp/lib/i386/libRcpp.a(Dimension.o
):Dimension.cpp:(.text+0x342): undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Unregister'
…………………………………………………………..
…………………………………………………………….
C:/Users/samuel/Documents/R/win-library/2.14/Rcpp/lib/i386/libRcpp.a(Environment
.o):Environment.cpp:(.text$_ZN4Rcpp11no_such_envC1Ei[Rcpp::no_such_env::no_such_
env(int)]+0x3fc): undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Unregister'
C:/Users/samuel/Documents/R/win-library/2.14/Rcpp/lib/i386/libRcpp.a(Environment
.o):Environment.cpp:(.text$_ZN4Rcpp11no_such_envC1Ei[Rcpp::no_such_env::no_such_
env(int)]+0x644): undefined reference to `_Unwind_SjLj_Resume'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'new'
* removing 'C:/Users/samuel/Documents/R/win-library/2.14/new'
```

Any advice on how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `package.skeleton` variant provided by Rcpp, or in this case, RcppArmadillo.  That is, call

```
 RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton(...)
```

not the one from base R.

You can also look at how the other CRAN packages that depend on RcppArmadillo are organised and compare the differences.

Comment: I tried using RcppArmadillo.package.skeleton(“new”,funs), It creates the directories and new.cpp file that contains MHcpp and IWcpp functions. Then I checked if the package “new” can be installed “Rcmd check new” this is what I get.
* checking for file 'new/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* checking package namespace information ... OK
* checking package dependencies ... OK
* checking if this is a source package ... OK
* checking if there is a namespace ... OK
* checking for executable files ... OK
* checking whether package 'new' can be installed ... ERROR
Installation failed.
What am I missing? Thanks

Comment: Thanks Dirk, the problem is solved. I was using Rtools213, removing the older version then installing the new "Rtools215" solved the issue.Agian thank for offering to help. RcppArmadillo is a great packages it speeded up my code by more that 70%.